# Nginix configuration for django nuxt app with docker hosted on ec2

Tags: django, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a dockerized app that works fine in development mode on my host machine. I'm trying to figure out how I can host my app on ec2 using the default ip address created when I launch my instance.

My folder structure is as follows.

```
backend
|---projectname
|---Dockerfile
|---requirements.txt 
|---wait-for-it.sh

config/nginx
|---app.conf

frontend
|---nuxt folders 
|---Dockerfile
```

This is my current docker compose file I'm using

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data  
    env_file: .env

    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    expose:
    - 5432  

redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis
    volumes:
    - redisdata:/data


django:
    build:
    context: ./backend
    env_file: .env

    command: >
    sh -c  "./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 && 
            cd autobets && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
            gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 autobets.wsgi:application" 
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
    - ./backend:/app
    depends_on:
    - db
    restart: on-failure


nuxt:
    build:
    context: ./frontend
    environment:
    - API_URI=http://django:8000/api

    command: bash -c "npm install && npm run dev"
    volumes:
    - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - django
    - redis

volumes:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
```

**config/nginx/app.config**

```
upstream django {
ip_hash;
server django:8000;
}

upstream nuxt {
ip_hash;
server nuxt:3000;
}

server {
location ~ /(api|admin|static)/ {
    proxy_pass http://django;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://nuxt;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
listen 8000;
server_name localhost;
}
```

Say if my ec2 domain name pointer is **ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com**
How do I set nginx up in my app to accept http connections to the frontend of my app?

On the backend localhost:8000/admin is my admin page I'd like to access this also using the ec2 domain name too.

What's the best way to alter my config so when I push my app after add the domain name pointer I can access my app hosted on ec2?

I've been reading documentation but can't find any helpful info for a dockerized django vue type app running on ec2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you need to make sure the security group attach to your box is open for incoming connection on port that NGinx listen

For each container you want to put on NGinx config you will need to find their  do to so do:

`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id`

NGinx is not inside a container,docker-compose so, nginx.conf

```
upstream django {
    ip_hash;
    server <container IP>:8000;     # <-- Change this, with container IP
}

upstream nuxt {
    ip_hash;
    server <container IP>:3000;     # <-- Change this, with container IP
}

server {
    location ~ /(api|admin|static)/ {
        proxy_pass @django               # <-- Change this, with container IP
        proxy_pass <container IP>:8000;  # <-- OR Change this, with container IP
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass @nuxt                # <-- Change this, add port
        proxy_pass <container IP>:3000  # <-- OR Change this, add port
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    }

    listen 8000;    # <-- Change port number, django already use this host port
    server_name localhost ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com;   # <-- change this line, add EC2 public domain
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    db:
        restart: always
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        env_file: .env

        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        expose:
            - 5432
        networks:           # <-- Add this
            - random_name   # <-- Add this

    redis:
        restart: always
        image: redis
        volumes:
            - redisdata:/data
        networks:           # <-- Add this
            - random_name   # <-- Add this

    django:
        build:
        context: ./backend
        env_file: .env

        command: >
            sh -c  "./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 &&
                    cd autobets && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
                    gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 autobets.wsgi:application"
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./backend:/app
        depends_on:
            - db
        restart: on-failure
        networks:           # <-- Add this
            - random_name   # <-- Add this


    nuxt:
        build:
        context: ./frontend
        environment:
            - API_URI=http://django:8000/api # <-- Wrong
            # From you Javascript on the client point of view,
            # you will request the public server, not the internal name of
            # you backend inside a container, that the public will never see
            - API_URI=http://ec2-52-204-122-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api # <-- Right
        command: bash -c "npm install && npm run dev"
        volumes:
            - ./frontend:/app
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
            - django    # <-- will become useless if change API_URI=
            - redis     # <-- bad design
        networks:           # <-- Add this
            - random_name   # <-- Add this

volumes:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
networks:           # <-- Add this
  - random_name:    # <-- Add this wanto make sure container can communicate
```

Security group on AWS should be open on the port you'll use for listening on NGinx, host 8000 is already used by django, so use another on

From app architecture POV, your backend should do the cache stuff with Redis, not the Frontend. Complexity or backend response caching should be cache on the backend somewhere on the controllers. You client should cache only statis assets. but you here to make you have working on a server, not to speak archi.

Comment: Do _not_ run `docker inspect` to look up the container-private IP addresses.  In this context, they will change whenever you redeploy your containers.  If the nginx proxy is running outside Docker on the same host, the `upstream` declarations can use `localhost` and the first published `ports:` numbers.  There's also no reason to modify the `docker-compose.yml` file to add `networks:` (and not use the Compose-provided `default` network).

Comment: @Jean-Jacques MOIROUX Thanks very much for your detailed answer. I haven't tried this yet. Should I actually deploy the app first to EC2 and then edit the nginx config? would that be best approach

Comment: Make it works first, to understand yourself the fix, why it work. Then when everything works you can start thinking automation, remake it better